# compiling images using angular cli command

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular2-aot

i have a simple angular project, where i have a image which is getting loaded from the image folder as shown in the [plunkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/NyAQFwiHYcUytl12oRj6/)

the real problem arises when i compile my project with the command ng build, after running the command, i get all the files compiled into the dist folder

-inline.bundle.js

-main.bundle.js

-polyfills.bundle.js

-styles.bundle.js

-vendor.bundle.js

and the images which i have refereed it in the app.component.css as url(../imgaes/pokemon.png) gets compiled with a hashname along with it and it is refreed from the root folder not from the folder which i have used to refer in the css file.

how can i overcome this hurdle, what i want is, the path should be same even after the we compile it. how can i do it

Comment: Use absolute path in place of relative path for image source in css

Comment: @AnkitKapoor thank you ankit, i think giving absolute path sollved my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use absolute path in place of relative path for image source in css